# Issue with Finder in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

So, I am using Drupal 7 and I'm having an issue with the Finder module.

I have a view set up with a list of a specific content type. In my Finder I have 2 select lists set up to filter the view, both with a blank option appended to the beginning, and also a text box.

When I view the page and select a value from either of the select lists the page works fine. The problem pops up when I leave both select lists blank and the text field empty. Instead of returning all results, which is the behavior I want, it return no results.

In the Finder module for my select lists I have 1 of the "Choices" set to Used Values and I have the field set to the correct content type I want to filter on. The 2nd Select List is set to "Available Options." Both Select Lists have the "Empty Choice" setting set to "empty."

If there is any other information I can provide, let me know.

This has been a very difficult bug to Google and I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered.....Sort of.

The problem turns out to be version of WebForm module that is being used. We were using version 7.x-4.3, which is the latest, but rolled back to version 7.x-4.1 and the issue resolved itself.

It seems odd to me that a product that is used by hundreds of thousands of people would let a bug this annoying slip by.